# What makes OpenCV so large on Windows? Anything I can do about it?

Tags: windows, opencv, emgucv

The OpenCV x64 distribution (through emgucv) for Windows has almost half a gigabyte of DLLs, including a single 224Mb opencv_gpu.dll.  It seems unlikely that any human could have produced that amount of code, so what gives?  Large embedded resources? Code generation bloat (this doesn't seem likely given that it's a native c/c++ project)

I want to use it for face recognition, but it's a problem to have such a large binary dependency in git, and it's a hassle to manage outside of source control.

[Update]
There are no embedded resources (at least the kind Windows DLLs usually have, but since this is a cross-platform product, I'm not sure that's significant.)  Maybe lots of initialized C table structures to perform matrix operations?

Comment: Are you aware of the kind of programming it takes to teach a computer to see?  :P  You say "i want to use it for face recognition" like it's no big deal, but there is *lots* of stuff going on behind the scenes.  We're basically talking a form of AI here.

Comment: So, what's your answer?  I'm asking the question as much out of curiosity as an expectation that I can somehow pull out just what I need.

Comment: I'd say get the source and build only what you need.  OpenCV covers a *lot* of stuff, and if you only need like 20% of it...

Comment: Agree. E.g. I have loaded the legacy module on my project and got rid of legacy.dll dependency. I also trimmed the code and kept only what's needed.

Comment: I suppose I could try that, though I'm not sure how to figure out what is used and what isn't in this particular area.  Not something I can spend a week figuring out (hence the question here)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The size of `opencv_gpu` is result of numerous template instantiations compiled for several CUDA architecture versions.

For example for convolution:

- 7 data types (from `CV_8U` to `CV_64F`)
- ~30 hadcoded sizes of convolution kernel
- 8 CUDA architectures (bin: 1.1 1.2 1.3 2.0 2.1(2.0) 3.0 + ptx: 2.0 3.0)

This produces about 1700 variants of convolution.
This way `opencv_gpu` can grow up to 1 Gb for the latest OpenCV release.

If you are not going to use any CUDA acceleration then you can safely drop the opencv_gpu.dll

Comment: Thank you.  I tried removing the gpu dll from the directory, but the app attempted to load it anyway.  I will try and exclude it from a custom build and see if I fare any better.